# BeautifulSoup Yahoo Finance Extract EPS

Tags: beautifulsoup, finance, yahoo

I am trying to extract EPS from Yahoo Finance but come out with a different figure I want. Can someone point out where went wrong?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {'User-Agents': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36 OPR/79.0.4143.50'}
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
print(soup.title.text)
```

Apple Inc. (AAPL) Stock Price, News, Quote & History - Yahoo Finance

```
price = soup.find('span', {'class': 'Trsdu(0.3s) '}).text
print(price)
```

146.92
By right I am expecting the answer is 5.11

[EPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kgNq.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Hi managed to get the solution via the Selenium xpath. Thanks to Google search and all's help. Got the answer I want. Which is 5.11

```
!pip install selenium
!apt-get update # to update ubuntu to correctly run apt install
!apt install chromium-chromedriver
!cp /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver /usr/bin
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)

wd = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
wd.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL")
EPS = wd.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="quote-summary"]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/span').text
print(EPS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using class as a CSS selector isn't very robust as there are many `span` elements with the class `Trsdu(0.3s)`.

To get EPS specifically, use this:

```py
price = soup.find('span', {'data-reactid': '153'})
print(price)
```

Which prints:

```
<span class="Trsdu(0.3s)" data-reactid="153">5.11</span>
```

Then you can simply:

```
price.text
```

Which will give you your required result:

```
5.11
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to use the "Copy selector".

[image: Copy selector]

### You can use this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agents': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36 OPR/79.0.4143.50'}
url = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL&.tsrc=fin-srch'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
result = soup.select('#quote-summary > div.D\(ib\).W\(1\/2\).Bxz\(bb\).Pstart\(12px\).Va\(t\).ie-7_D\(i\).ie-7_Pos\(a\).smartphone_D\(b\).smartphone_W\(100\%\).smartphone_Pstart\(0px\).smartphone_BdB.smartphone_Bdc\(\$seperatorColor\) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td.Ta\(end\).Fw\(600\).Lh\(14px\) > span')[0].text
print(result)
```

### Output:

```
5.11
```